# java app developement error is not enclosing class

Tags: java, android

Hey this is my first time using stack overflow and I am trying to call a class in a different file (MainActivity calling FetchWeatherTask) I am getting the error is not an enclosing class this is code is throwing the error

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item){
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
            ForecastFragment.FetchWeatherTask weatherTask = new ForecastFragment.FetchWeatherTask();
            weatherTask.execute();
            return true;
        }
```

im going to try a few things but I am stuck the full error is

'com.alpha.(appName).ForecastFragment' is not an enclosing class

EDIT:

im trying to call a class in a different file to get the weather data

Comment: you only included part of your class, so it's hard to be sure, but in the code you posted, you are missing a closing `}`.

Comment: Which line gives the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ForecastFragment.FetchWeatherTask weatherTask = new ForecastFragment.FetchWeatherTask();
```

This line of code tells the Java compiler to look for the `FetchWeatherTask` class inside the `ForecastFragment` class. Since the compiler cannot find `FetchWeatherTask` there, it complains. I suspect that you have declared `FetchWeatherTask` as a top-level class, so you can simply remove both `ForecastFragment` prefixes (and the dot as well).

Comment: Thanks I realized after reading this that I had FetchWeatherTask inside the other class and I moved it to its own file and everything see,s alright

Answer (score 0):

You can use Handlers to perform tasks that run in background. Also try to run an Async task by either extending the AsyncTask or starting a new thread manually.

Comment: in this im trying to run a class that gets weather data from open weather map which extends asynctask im still fairly new to this